# DAX Column to count by category

Tags: count, powerbi, categories

I am trying to create a DAX Column that counts the occurrences in a month. Power BI built-in table function already counts them by category, but I need to create a column that saves the result in order to compare it to other values.

In the picture below you can see the 3 columns: The "Count" column is what I am trying to compute and it should return the same result as the "ID" column, but you can see that it only returns the total number of entries and not by categories.

Any idea how I could compute it? Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Denis

[image]

Comment: Sorry but your question is not clear. What do you mean by "saves the result"? If the result should be the same as the ID column then why not just use the ID column? What's the difference? Perhaps give a small example dataset together with expected results, explaining clearly how you arrive at those results.

Comment: Saves the result - in that the number will remain in the new created column and won't disappear if I use filters. 

The column ID only shows what I'd like to have as result, but in this case it is useless to use. 

I actually want to create a Chi-square Test that is automatically calculated when I modify the filters. The nature of the Chi-square requires to compute some expected values and some "observed" values. In my case, I want to compute those "observed" values in a new column so that I can compare them to the "expected" values.

Comment: So you want a column which duplicates the ID entries but which is unaffected by any filtering except for the month number?

Comment: yes, but I have solved it now. appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by category, but I think this should get you in the ballpark:

```
Count = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[ID ]),
    FILTER('Table',EARLIER('Table'[Month])='Table'[Month]))
```

Maybe you need a COUNT instead of a SUM, or a different column, but the FILTER(...,EARLIER()) is the important part.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Great job! thank you for the help!